# Prove: $|\mathbb{N}|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove: $|\mathbb{N}|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$

**Note:** $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality.

**My work**

Suppose $|\mathbb{N}|\geq |\mathbb{R}|$

We can write $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb N\cup(\mathbb Q-\mathbb N)\cup\mathbb{I}$ then  $$|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb N\cup(\mathbb Q-\mathbb N) \cup \mathbb{I}| = |\mathbb{N}| + |\mathbb{Q-N}| + |\mathbb{I}| = |\mathbb{N}| + |\mathbb{Q}| - |\mathbb{N}|+|\mathbb{I}|$$

Then,

$$|\mathbb{N}|+|\mathbb{Q}|-|\mathbb{N}|+|\mathbb{I}|\leq|\mathbb{N}|\implies |\mathbb{Q}|+|\mathbb{I}|\leq|\mathbb{N}|$$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Huh? But $\mathbb N\subset\mathbb R$, no?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{I}$ the set of irrationals? I usually denote that as $\mathbb{K}$ so I’m just clarifying.

Comment: yes, is the irrationals.

Comment: What you should suppose is $|\Bbb N|>|\Bbb R|$ if you wish to work by contradiction.

Comment: Why the down vote? OP has shown his effort, and the problem is clear.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But the opposite to $\leq$ is $>$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I have reached my daily voting limit. Otherwise, I would have upvoted.

Comment: You write that $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{N}\cup (\mathbb{Q} - \mathbb{N})\cup \mathbb{I}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ follows that $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{R}|$.

Of course $\mathbb{N}\neq\mathbb{R}$ because the cardinalities are different, so by writing that $|\mathbb{N}|\leqslant|\mathbb{R}|$ is technically incorrect.

Comment: You need to show (1) There is at least one one-to-one function from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb R$ (that part is easy) and (2) No such function is onto $\mathbb R$ (that takes more work). However, you shouldn't simply assume in this context that either $|A|<|B|$ or $|A|\ge|B|.$ As applied to infinite sets, that is a substantial statement in its own right.

Comment: @MichaelHardy This question is only about (1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The embedding map $j:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $j(x)=x$ is trivially an injection and the claim follows.

Comment: The only sentence in this whole thread that actually gives an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$, $|\mathbb{N}|\leqslant|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Q}$ but $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Q}|$ since there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Indeed. And your point is… ?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was a strict inequality, my bad